# Why would IISManager Bindings dialog show a different Certificate than 'netsh http' command?

Tags: ssl, iis

I've scoured SO and just about every other source I could think of and can't find an answer to this bizarre scenario I've run into.

I recently renewed a wildcard certificate and installed it on my server (Windows Server 2012 DC). I used the netsh command to delete the old cert and add the new.  i.e.

```
netsh http delete sslcert hostnameport=syncaccess-swc-nap.syncronex.com:443
netsh http add sslcert hostnameport=syncaccess-swc-nap.syncronex.com:443 certhash=A6F49B... certstorename=MY appid='{3a9c5b05-1a95-43f4...}'
```

This all worked as expected.  The server is issuing the expected (newer) SSL Cert according to my browsers.  If I run `netsh http show sslcert` on the server, I see the expected certificate hash.  By all accounts, this worked perfectly.

However, when I view the site bindings within IIS Manager, it still shows the old certificate.  This makes me nervous even though everything seems to be working.

Here's the output from `netsh http show sslcert` for this particular site:
[image]

And this is what IISManager shows:
[image]

The 'friendly name' of that cert in the IIS manager dialog is the old cert's name (new one is 2021-syncronex.com) and you can see that the hash's don't match up.

I've tried restarting the site/application pool.  I've tried rebooting the server.  It doesn't seem to be a caching sort of situation.

It's probably important to note that there are about two dozen sites on the server.  All of them are bound to this wildcard cert *and some of them have multiple SSL bindings using SNI*.  This particular site does not use SNI and only carries a single https binding.

I've got several sites that are exhibiting this same odd behavior.

So, what did I do wrong there?  I'm hoping this is just a peculiarity of IIS Manager and that I can safely assume things are working correctly.

Comment: You misunderstood the mapping, and IIS Manager always works in its own way, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background To resolve the issue, enable SNI for this binding.

Answer (score 3):

Lex Li comment gave me the hints I needed.  The "thing I did wrong" is I left out a step in my deployment to update the certificate binding on my default web site.  I have a default web site set up to support older browsers that can't use SNI, but I completely forgot about it when constructing my deployment scripts.  Once I changed my scripts to ensure that the default web site binding was updated, everything fell back into place (so-to-speak), and the IIS Manager binding dialog matches my expectations for both my SNI sites and non-SNI sites.